# VSCode WSL-2 Proxy Problem: Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies

Tags: proxy, settings, wsl-2

#### Problem Description

When I was using Node.js and generated the file `package.jons`, I found there's a warning at the start:

```
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies: ["SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1090","SOCKS 127.0.0.1:1090"].
```

#### Possible Reason

Then I searched the error message `Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies`, and found **maybe it's a wsl2 proxy problem** according to [this github reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136598#issuecomment-962926338).

For more precise reason, I searched the [VSCode proxy document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support) metioned by the reply, and found **maybe it's caused by wrong proxy setting**.

#### Ways to try

According to the VSCode document, I want to **try the setting of "Manual proxy address"**. But I encountered two problems:

1. I don't know how to run the command line mentioned in the VSCode document: `--proxy-server=<scheme>=<uri>[:<port>][;...] | <uri>[:<port>] | "direct://"`.
2. I don't know where to find the file `/etc/resolv.conf` mentioned in the github reply to get the wsl server ip.

Answer (score 0):

When I switch my VPN into global mode and restart VSCode, the warning disappear.